# Travis CI can't find the release files for a GitHub deployment

Tags: go, build, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I can't get Travis CI to find my release folder for deployment, despite trying the other answers on SO.

I have a Makefile that runs release like this:

```
release:
        mkdir -p release
        env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-linux-amd64 $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-darwin-amd64 $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-windows-amd64.exe $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        echo Releases in $(pwd)/release
        ls release
```

In the [log](https://travis-ci.com/MarkEdmondson1234/gago) it says the release are in `/release/*`

```
mkdir -p release

env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o release/gagocli-vv0.6-linux-amd64 github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/gago/gagocli

env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -o release/gagocli-vv0.6-darwin-amd64 github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/gago/gagocli

env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o release/gagocli-vv0.6-windows-amd64.exe github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/gago/gagocli

echo Releases in /release

Releases in /release

ls release

gagocli-vv0.6-darwin-amd64

gagocli-vv0.6-linux-amd64

gagocli-vv0.6-windows-amd64.exe
```

(I have tried `release/*`  as well) but when I set my travis (including the `skip_cleanup: true`  that fixed other problems) it can't find the files:

```
Deploying to repo: MarkEdmondson1234/gago

Current tag is: v0.6

/release/* does not exist.
```

(same result with `release/*`)

The files are created though, from what I see in the log.

My current travis - the `file:` line is the source of the issue:

```
before_deploy:
- make release
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key:
    secure: FSk8DEG1vae8uUYaV+etc/umwescm0eV072jvTS6GarzlA=
  file: /release/*
  on:
    repo: MarkEdmondson1234/gago
    tags: true
```

Can anyone help me help travis deploy find my files?

Answer (score 1):

I think it was something to do with globs, as when I tried with explicit files it worked:

Makefile:

```
release:
        mkdir -p release
        env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-linux-amd64 $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-darwin-amd64 $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o release/$(CLI)-$(VERSION)-windows-amd64.exe $(BINARY_NAME_CLI)
        ls release
```

Travis file:

```
env:
  global:
    - GAGO_AUTH=${GOPATH}/auth.json
    - VERSION=${TRAVIS_TAG}
before_deploy:
- make release
deploy:
  provider: releases
  skip_cleanup: true
  api_key:
    secure: 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
  file: 
    - release/gagocli-${VERSION}-linux-amd64
    - release/gagocli-${VERSION}-darwin-amd64
    - release/gagocli-${VERSION}-windows-amd64.exe
  on:
    repo: MarkEdmondson1234/gago
    tags: true
```